# Search and get information about each value in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I have an app where i search data depending by name from the input. So, for example: if i select 'John' i get the object that contains info about John. 
I want to improve the application, because now if i write 'Mike' or i select 'Mike' i get the object that contains information about Mike (in the console), but if i select the second name, EX: if i will have in the input "Mike John", i get an empty array. 
I want to solve this issue plus to save all objects that contains info about each names, when i will click on the button using `saveBtn` function. How to solve the  my issue?

link to my app: https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-frost-skle2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution to your issue:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-austin-ih1o8

The main issue was that on your `search` function you were filtering based on a concatenated string (a result of `selectedItems.join(",")` and looking for it in the `elements` array which always returned `false` and resulted in an empty array.

for example
you were searching for:
`"mike,john"` inside:

```
//after JSON.stringify() and toLowerString():
 {
    "key": "1",
    "name": "mike",
    "age": 32,
    "address": "10 downing street"
  },
```

Some other things I changed in your solution was removing the unnecessary `slice`, and using the [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method in order to find the element which matches at least one of your `selectedItems`

As for saving, I've `alert`ed your `search` output - but you can do anything you like with it. For example, you can reset the selected items using `setState([]);`

Comment: how to reset the input after i push save? ex: i click, after that to remove all selected items from select.

Comment: @Asking - I've updated my answer and the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-austin-ih1o8) to include resetting after save.

Comment: could you help me with this: Now if i  click on `save` after i inserted 2 names i get an an array with 2 objects. After that if i will insert just 1 name and click `save`, the previous array is changed with a new one which is composed only from 1 element, in fact i deleted the first array, but i don't want to lose the previous array. I want to keep the previous array, and if i will add a value that not exists in the previous array, i want to add it, and i fact i will have an array with 3 objects. Could you help me, please?

Comment: What you can do is keep another state for the accumulated items.
I've updated the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-austin-ih1o8) and left comments explaining the last additions.